How do I remove the default value defined by the dto property in the @nestjs/swagger PartialType function?
CreateAdminDto.ts
export class CreateAdminDto {
  readonly username!: string;

  @IsOptional()
  readonly jurisdiction?: string | null = null;


  @IsOptional()
  readonly nickname?: string;
}

UpdateAdminDto.ts
export class UpdateAdminDto extends PartialType(OmitType(CreateAdminDto, ['username'])) {}

In CreateAdminDto, I defined a jurisdiction attribute and set the default value. In UpdateAdminDto, I used @nestjs/swagger PartialType function, and when I update, I don't pass the jurisdiction attribute, but it does have a default value. How do I remove this default value?


PartialType is just a type definition, it does not strip the value at runtime. At runtime, CreateAdminDto is instantiated when UpdateAdminDto is instantiated, therefore firstName has a default value of admin. Use a different DTO. Also, most likely unless it's a very basic CRUD application, the DTO used to Create and the DTO used to Update are not going to match.

https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/1276465626470158367/1276608711107809433

likely because the update Dto uses the createDto
export class UpdateAdminDto extends PartialType(CreateAdminDto) {}
basicly means take the CreateAdminDto and make all fields optional then apply that to the UpdateAdminDto

https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/1276465626470158367/1276608414109270068

The discord link in your answer could not be opened
